# Hiding OAuth Callback URL Parameters

Tags: oauth2, workbench

I am trying to recreate user experience of the login functionality found at https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php.  I believe it is utilizing the OAuth Web Server Authentication Flow as shown at:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm

I have successfully implemented this.  However, I notice the login user experience of my application is not the same as workbench.  My app works as described in the documentation linked.  After successfully logging in, you are sent to the callback url with the `code` parameter appended to the url.  I notice that when you login with Workbench, the callback url (https://workbench.developerforce.com/select.php) does not display the `code` parameter.  There does not appear to be an intermediate page consuming the parameter either.

Is workbench not using the same OAuth flow?  Is there perhaps something that it does to hide the `code` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workbench is using the same OAuth web server flow explained in the [document](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm) you followed. The callback URL is even using the `code` parameter, but it [redirects to `select.php`](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/forceworkbench/blob/1fd192294a37ecb74d6a7b213874e0f7dd7c2d7f/workbench/controllers/LoginController.php#L349-L426) so quickly that you're not seeing it. If you use something like the Developer Tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox, you'll see the login on Workbench actually goes something like this:

```
POST https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

[302 Redirect to SFDC]

GET  https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&display=popup&client_id=[workbench client id]&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fworkbench.developerforce.com%2Flogin.php&state=%7B%22host%22%3A%22login.salesforce.com%22%2C%22apiVersion%22%3A%2227.0%22%2C%22csrfToken%22%3A%22408dbaeeeabe6960450995905746c5f0%22%7D

[User logs into SFDC]

GET  https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php?display=popup&code=aPrx99xAfwRScfJXtDmvAWEIGIy6Av5Ck4a2OqtYg8017p_N57e7dlHC1xtC9LFI_7xIdi.ZqQ%3D%3D&state=%7B%22host%22%3A%22login.salesforce.com%22%2C%22apiVersion%22%3A%2227.0%22%2C%22csrfToken%22%3A%22408dbaeeeabe6960450995905746c5f0%22%7D

[302 Redirect to select.php]

GET  https://workbench.developerforce.com/select.php
```